# Eclipse Launch Configuration Blank Issue for Applet

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, applet

I have a dynamic web project that I've created with Maven in Eclipse Kepler. I need to use an applet in my web application. But, deploying applet with web content in Eclipse is problem, actually Eclipse deploys applet files to web-inf files but we can not access Web-Inf files directly in web application. For that reason, I exported that applet to my WebContent folder. If I don't use external classes in applet, there is no error. I mean, if I do not import any external classes, there will not be any problem.

But I need to import some other java classes. When I export applet to jar, other java classes that applet needs are not exist in the jar. I figured out that if I export applet to runnable jar, other classes will be exist in jar package.

In Eclipse, I can not export applet to runnable. There is configuration in run configuration, under Applet tab, I can run it in Eclipse. But when I export it to runnable jar, launch configuration is always blank. I deleted my configurations, everything is same.

Here is my configurations :

[image: Launch Configuration in Export]
[image: Run Configuration]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applet is not an executable jar-file. Use export to JAR file. And add your manifest.

Comment: Another computer can build runnable jar file from applet.

Comment: Then the applet must be coded as an hybrid application/applet.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).